# Creating 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am facing an issue while creating a 3D array from a dataframe with many columns. The query is as below:

```
x1 = data1    
cols = list(data1.drop(['xyz', 'Date_Time'], axis=1).columns)

x1 = x1.drop_duplicates(subset=['xyz','Date_Time'], keep='first')

x = []
x = np.empty((data1.shape[0], data1.shape[1],len(cols)))
a=[]
for i in range(len(cols)):
  a = x1.pivot(index='xyz', columns = 'Date_Time', values=cols[i])
  a.fillna(0,inplace=True)
  x = np.concatenate((x,a[a.shape[0],a.shape[1],None]), axis=2)
```

The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [(3032, 267, None)] of type  to Timestamp

Comment: Can you add your `import` statements please

Comment: once you use the line `a = x1.pivot(index='xyz', columns = 'Date_Time', values=cols[i])` `a` is no longer a list and is now a dataframe

Comment: also, I don't think this line is doing what you think it is, `x = np.concatenate((x,a[a.shape[0],a.shape[1],None]), axis=2)`,

`a[a.shape[0],a.shape[1],None]` should be returning an index out of bounds exception

Comment: hi and welcome! Please explicit what you would like as an output